HTTP Get-запросы на .netFramework 4.8
Был написан код для парсинга автозапчастей на .net 8 через HttpClient, работает отлично но при переносе на .NetFramework v4.8 запросы отдают Forbidden, пробывал разные заголовки, скорее всего дело не в них, а а в самом клиенте. Немного кода
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

        using var client = new HttpClient();


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");

        
        repeat:
        await Task.Delay(500);
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://exist.ua/api/v1/fulltext/search-v2/?query=6207");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Response JSON:");
            InitialSearch.Root res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InitialSearch.Root>(responseBody);

            foreach (var item in res.result.products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ID: {item.id}, Description: {item.description}, Price: {item.price}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
            goto repeat;
        }


Не может этот код работать на .NET.. В любом случае, вы забыли один или несколько заголовков, вот вам и дает такую ошибку. По моим мелким наблюдениям, достаточно добавить client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

Этот код не для .NET Framework 4.8.
